Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb ...'
I'm able to build the image locally in my machine (Docker version 20.10.18), but failing in Bitbucket pipeline for an environment using Docker version 20.10.8.
Eveything works fine for image php:8.0-fpm but not for php:8.3-fpm.
Detailed error message here
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [169 kB]

Fetched 9225 kB in 1s (9126 kB/s)

Reading package lists...

E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'

E: Sub-process returned an error code

The command '/bin/sh -c curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODEJS_VERSION}.x | bash -     && apt update && apt install -y git     cron     default-mysql-client     build-essential     gnupg     jpegoptim optipng gifsicle pngquant     libjpeg-dev libfreetype-dev libpng-dev     zlib1g-dev libzip-dev     openssh-client     libicu-dev     nodejs     gosu     gettext-base     brotli     unzip     apache2 libapache2-mod-fcgid     && docker-php-ext-configure zip     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg     && docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl     && docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo_mysql zip opcache bcmath exif intl pcntl' returned a non-zero code: 100

ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build : Build failed

This is my Dockerfile
ARG PHP_VERSION
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm AS base-image

ENV PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS=0 \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_ACCELERATED_FILES=20000 \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION=256 \
    APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/code/htdocs

ARG NODEJS_VERSION
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODEJS_VERSION}.x | bash - \
    && apt update && apt install -y git \
    cron \
    default-mysql-client \
    build-essential \
    gnupg \
    jpegoptim optipng gifsicle pngquant \
    libjpeg-dev libfreetype-dev libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev libzip-dev \
    openssh-client \
    libicu-dev \
    python3 \
    nodejs \
    gosu \
    gettext-base \
    brotli \
    unzip \
    python3-pip \
    apache2 libapache2-mod-fcgid \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo_mysql zip opcache bcmath exif intl pcntl



Depending on the purpose of this container image, I'd advise to just don't build it like that. Why would you need php, python and node in the same container?

I don't see how is this related to bitbucket pipelines. Would you please [edit] the question and remove that tag?

I'd suspect the curl https://remote-script | bash - && more-commands is not being properly associated. I'd try
RUN (curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODEJS_VERSION}.x | bash - ) \
    && apt update && apt install -y \
    git \
    cron \
    default-mysql-client \
    # etc...



Solution to the problem :
Update Docker version.
